# Recuperar variables para compararlas y desabilitar boton de envio

Tags: javascript, ajax

tengo un boton con la clase **limite_stock** ,el cual quiero desabilitarlo cuando el stock este lleno, para saberlo tengo las variables **stock** y **stock_maximo**, pero al hacerle debug veo que no tienen valor. Help porfavor no veo como puedo hacerlo.
Cualquier ayuda sera muy bien recibida.
Gracias

```javascript
var username = localStorage.username;
var url = "http://www.xxxxxxx.php?username=" + username + "&busca-stock=";
    
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    
    if (data.busca-stock != null && (" + data.stock + " != " + data.stock_maximo + ")) {
    
    alert(" + data.stock + ");
   
    $(".limite-stock").click(function () {
        $(".limite-stock").attr("disabled", true);
    });
    
    $.each(data.busca-stock, function(i, data) {
        $("#listado-stock").append(
            //falta un if 
            "<div id='" + data.stock +  
            "'></div><div id='" +  
            data.stock_maximo + "'></div><div id='" +  
            data.stock_maximo +  
            "'></div><button class='**limite-stock**' id='" +  
            data.reg_id + "'></button>");
                });
            } else {
                $("#listado-stock").html("No Existe stock");
            }
    });
    
    $(document).on('click', '.limite-stock', function() {
    
      var reg_id = $(this).attr("id");
      var username = localStorage.username;
    
      var stock=" + data.stock + ";
      var stock_maximo=$('" + data.stock_maximo + "');
      alert(stock);
    
      var dataString = "reg_id=" + reg_id +  
        "&username=" + username + "&limite-stock=";
            
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "http://www.xxxxx.php",
        crossDomain: true,
        cache: false,
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
          if (data == "true") {
            alert("true");
          } else {
            alert("false");
          }
        }
      });
    });
```

---

Ejemplo json

```json
{
   "busca-stock":[
      {
         "reg_id":"64",
         "reg_date":"09-09-20 07:54:34",
         "username":"pacoperez@gmail.com",
         "modelo":"seat",
         "ref":"Blanco",
         "stock-maximo":"22",
         "stock":"0",
         "status":"true"
      }
   ]
}
```

```
//--------busca-stock
else if(isset($_GET['busca-stock'])){
    $reg_id=$_POST['reg_id'];
    $username=$_GET['username'];
    $q=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM `coches` WHERE `username`='$username' and `status`='true");
    while ($f=mysqli_fetch_object($q)) {
        $busca-stock[]=$f;
    }
    echo '{"busca-stock":'.json_encode($busca-stock).'}';
}
//------- limite-stock
else if(isset($_POST['.limite-stock'])){
    $reg_id=$_POST['reg_id'];
    $username=$_POST['username'];
    $q=mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE `coches` SET stock = stock+1 WHERE `reg_id`='$reg_id'");
    if($q){
        echo "true";
    }
    else
        echo "false";
}
```

Comment: Podrías ponernos un ejemplo del Json? aparte me llama la atención  `(" + data.stock + " != " + data.stock_maximo + ")` ya que probablemente esté mal. Si deseas comparar esas dos variables recibidas con `data.stock != data.stock_maximo` sería suficiente

Comment: Hice lo que me digiste y sigo teniendo problema con variables undefine (data.stock y data.stock_maximo).

Comment: El resto es todo correcto, me trae la array, el id y el username. gracias

Comment: El ejemplo que has puesto  es lo que recibes en `json_encode($busca-stock)` ?

Comment: Si es el json que recibo

Comment: Entiendo que también debiera que modificar la función de php limite-stock, es cierto?

Comment: En el ejemplo que pones no aparece limite-stock, no se de donde lo recoges

Comment: falta un `if` en tu `$("#listado-stock").append` por favor corrígelo.

Answer (score 0):

Estas tratando mal el objeto, estas intentando obtener un valor de un objeto que está dentro de otro, con un ejemplo podemos verlo mejor:

```js
var ObjNormal = [{"dato1":"Valor1","dato2":"Valor2","dato3":"Valor3" }];
var ObjMultidimensional = {"Datos":[{"dato1":"Valor1","dato2":"Valor2","dato3":"Valor3" }]}

$(document).ready(function(){
    //recorro el normal
  $.each(ObjNormal,function(item,value){
    console.log("ObjNormal",value.dato1);
    console.log("ObjNormal",value.dato2);
    console.log("ObjNormal",value.dato3);
  });
  //recorro el multidimensional
   $.each(ObjMultidimensional,function(item,value){
    //dividido el multidimensional, recojo los subvalores
     $.each(value,function(subItem,subValue){
            console.log("ObjMultidimensional",subValue.dato1);
        console.log("ObjMultidimensional",subValue.dato2);
        console.log("ObjMultidimensional",subValue.dato3);
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Haces un primer recorrido pero falta un segundo para acceder a la información que requieres.